# Hibernate reverse engineering - custom constructor

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I came across a problem in a hibernate reverse engineering of the DB.

I have got a table `ADDRESS` with many columns (as you would expect from address), but not many of them are actually constrained with `NOT NULL`.

For a long time, reveng generated class so there existed constructor like this:

```
Address(AddressId, Account, Date, String, String);
```

Currently, it only generates empty constructor, full constructor and single one parameter constructor

```
public Address(AddressId id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

I would need to convince hibernate to create the constructor above with 5 params. Is it possible somehow? Those 5 params are those that are declared `NOT NULL` in DB.

I am using Java 8 and I am connecting to Oracle DB. `AddressId` is generated class based on composite Primary Key of the `Address`. `Account` is another class in DB and `Address` has a Foreign Key that links to `Account` PK.

Comment: Why don't you create the constructor for yourself? Or do you really reverse engineer your data base over and over again?

Comment: the classes generated by hibernate are generated every time from scratch during every build to cover for possible DB changes.